# Adding popup message box before tool execution with ArcPy and ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, python-2.6

I want to add a box message to pop up before execution of a button tool. When I click a button which will do geoprocessing, I want a box to appear on view before processing with message that I am about to do xxx processing.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 3):

See [Python Message Box Without huge library dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485610/python-message-box-without-huge-library-dependancy) at Stack Overflow.

Note that doing any sort of user interface in a geoprocessing tool is kind of a no-no and may annoy your end users.

Answer (score 1):

The geoprocesing framework has a standard user interface for built-in geoprocessing tools, models and script tools. Unless you are doing something that really requires its own specialized user interface, you should stick to the framework.

See the following help topics for more information:

- [What is geoprocessing?](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/What_is_geoprocessing/002s00000001000000/)
- [A quick tour of creating script tools](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001500000006000000.htm)
- [Writing messages in script tools](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Writing_messages_in_script_tools/00150000000p000000/)
- [Customizing script tool behavior](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Customizing_script_tool_behavior/00150000000t000000/)

If you will be upgrading to 10.1 soon you might also be interested in [Python toolboxes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_is_a_Python_toolbox/001500000022000000/) and [Python add-ins](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//014p00000025000000).

Comment: Just to clear: It is a specialized user interface and therefore require a separate message window (not 'arcpy.AddMessage' for in script messages) as a notification on screen before execution of customized tool.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the python framework implemented in ArcGIS (referred to above) is very limiting.  For people that are used to professional design systems like visual studio, this stuff will pull your hair out. Even the add-ins do not get you forms with controls, just single controls on the ArcGIS toolbars.  Most developers want to develop interfaces (e.g. forms with controls)

If you want complete control over ArcGIS systems you need to code up in Visual Studio and ArcObjects.